# Calling Resources.Load on a texture is not working

Tags: c#, resources, unity-game-engine, textures

I'm trying to load a `Texture` from the `Resources` folder but it keeps on returning `null`.

```
t = (Texture)Resources.Load("Circle") as Texture;
```

The circle texture has an extension of `.tga`.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Added the C# tag for you.

Comment: Why cast to Texture and then try to parse the result to a Texture again?

Comment: t = Resources.Load("Circle") as Texture;

Comment: I tried it this way too, I thought that maybe not casting it might've been the problem.

Comment: What about the path? Is it Assets/Resources/Circle.tga ?

Comment: Yes, that is the path.

Comment: public texture t = Resources.Load("Circle") as Texture;   Try if that gives you some sort of error debug. Or that it still stays null . IF it stays null check capitalisation of your circle. Also check in editor if stays empty ofcourse ;)

Answer (score 2):

You must put Circle.tga in Assets/Resources folder. Plus if you have subfolder, for example Resources/Textures/Circle.tga then do like this:

```
Texture t = Resources.Load("Textures/Circle") as Texture;
```

Comment: "You must put Circle.tga in Assets/Resources folder." Thanks for this line.

Answer (score 2):

The extension of the file isn't necessary. So this is correct:

```
t = (Texture)Resources.Load("Circle") as Texture;
```

This is not:

```
t = (Texture)Resources.Load("Circle.npg") as Texture;
```

Answer (score 2):

## Single Texture File

Texture File should be added into **Resources** folder
After that use below lines of code for load texture

```
var Texture_1 : Texture2D;
Texture_1 = Resources.Load("TextureName");
```

## For Folder

Folder should be in kept into **Resources** folder
After that use below lines of code for load folder of textures

```
var textures : Object[];
textures = Resources.LoadAll("FolderName");
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem was the "Resources" folder, I did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

@Massimiliano Uguccioni
thanks... that fixed my problem.

**Steps to use Resources.load:**

1. make sure its in the Resources folder
2. reference full relative path without Resources: eg: textures/texture1 where textures is a folder inside Resources
3. like Massimiliano Uguccioni said dont include file extension