# Load material from assets in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, unityscript

In my Assets folder I have a folder named Material where I stored all the needed materials, One of the materials in the Material folder is `Night_Sky`, which I want at a certain moment of the game to replace the `day_sky` and set `Night_sky` as my default Skybox. I tried many codes all of them return null object, examples :

```
night = Resources.Load("Material", typeof(Material)) as Material;
```

or

```
night = Resources.Load("Material/Night_Sky.mat", typeof(Material)) as Material;
```

How can I load my `Night_Sky` material, or if there is an easier way to switch my skybox to `night_sky` thank you for sharing it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will not work as Resources.Load requires you to place the object in the Resources folder. This information can also be found in the [Unity Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)

For this to properly work you will need to create a folder called Resources Inside the Assets folder. After which you can add the Material folder to this. So the folder structure would look as following

```
Assets/Resources/Materials/Night_Sky.mat
```

Further more the script to load the material looks just fine.

If you really do not wish to use the resources folder, you can try to obtain the materials using System.IO folder search options instead. But I would advice you to just use the build in Resources function.

When you do use the `Resources.Load()` however, you will need to keep a few things in mind. The `path` is case-sensitive and requires you to add the file extension as well. So in the example above, that would result in:

```
myMaterial = Resources.Load("Materials/Night_Sky.mat");
```

### Unity 5.0 or >

As [Nika Kasradze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3183423/nika-kasradze) mentioned in the comments. In unity 5.0 or up  extensions must be omitted. Making the correct [unity5](/questions/tagged/unity5) syntax

```
myMaterial = Resources.Load("Materials/Night_Sky");
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I tried different things, but loading the Material never works. Tried also different directories as well as with and without suffix but the Material always stays null. Setting the material inside a public variable inside the inspector is no problem. But I really would like to know how to load it programmatically.

Comment: @亚历山大 if it is not working make sure of the following things `case sensitivity` the path is case sensitive. `casting to type` As material or typeof(material) are required. `file extension` is also required to be added. And to load it you have to cast the path from Resources, so in the example above it would result in `myMaterial = Resources.Load("Materials/Night_Sky.mat");` You can also take a look at the answer given on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092200/calling-resources-load-on-a-texture-is-not-working)

Comment: I can get Material with the help of last comment `myMaterial = Resources.Load("Materials/Night_Sky.mat");` Thanks a lot..